# What Community XSLT 2 libraries exist?

Tags: open-source, xslt-2.0

What XSLT 2.0 libaries are publicly available which:

- Are either free, Open Source or have minimal copy-right or patent limitations;
- Are general purpose in nature; and
- Are not tied down to any platform or XSLT implementation?

Through Google, I have found the following 3, but maybe there are others?

- xsltsl.sourceforge.net (XSLT Standard Library)
- www.xsltfunctions.com (FunctX)
- fxsl.sourceforge.net (FXSL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also EXPath http://expath.org/, I mention it although it probably does not meet your third requirement "not tied down to any platform or XSLT implementation" as it looks like most stuff is specified generally but then implementations are often only available as part of one or some particular XSLT or XQuery implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[XSLT-SB](http://code.google.com/p/xslt-sb/wiki/Index) fits to your description.

Answer (score 0):

I found two more:

- http://wwbota.free.fr/XSLT_models/README.htm
- http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT